# Power Query: List of Tables Loaded into Separate Sheets

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have created a list of tables in Power Query:

[image]

Each table contains data that relates to each Ticker Symbol:

[image]

I would now like to create a separate Sheet for each Ticker symbol with each of those Sheets populated by the data in the Table.

However, I have no idea how to do this.  I have done a variety of searches online, but can't find any solutions.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power Query can only load to a single sheet at a time. To achieve what you want, click expand as highlighted. This will loads all the data to a single sheet.

[image]

Now you're back in Excel, create a pivot from your new table. Add ticker symbol to the filter section. On the ribbon, click options and show report filter pages and Excel will generate a sheet per each symbol for you.

[image]